# C++ library for fixed-size matrices and vectors

Tags: c++, matrix, cuda, cross-platform, linear-algebra

I am looking for a C++ fixed-size matrix library which would implement most common operations for vectors and matrices in the same way as **boost::numeric::ublas** does, but to be used **within** *CUDA kernels* (and thus be *fixed-size* to use only local memory and not global memory accesses).

I found several host-based matrix libraries: *boost::numeric::ublas*, *Eigen*, *blitz*, but they do not have fixed-size matrices I could use with CUDA on my kernels.
*Eigen* has *Matrix3f* and corresponding stuff which is *what I am looking for*, but it does not survive compilation with nvcc (though there seems to be some progress in that direction, see [here](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lib.eigen/3762) ).

**Edit**: I'm doing all that stuff on Linux, and thus would like to possibly have something cross-platform...

Comment: CUBLAS ? https://developer.nvidia.com/cublas

Comment: I'm not exactly familiar with what you are asking, but I do know (my knowledge comes first-hand because I work on ArrayFire) that a lot of Eigen users are using ArrayFire for GPU computing since there is a lot of overlap in functionality. Benchmarks comparing Eigen and ArrayFire are here:  http://www.accelereyes.com/products/benchmarks_arrayfire  Cheers!

Comment: @accelereyes: the target is to use linear algebra stuff within CUDA kernels, and from what I understand ArrayFire is to compute linear algebra things for the CPU by the GPU. My target is not that. It's for the **GPU**, by the GPU (thus not using any parallelism for linear algebra operations).

Comment: @SteveTownsend: seems like CUBLAS 5 might have some new stuff which can be run on the device, but I didn't find anything interesting about it yet (plus I am with CUDA 4 right now).

Comment: @AlexandreKaspar What you are asking for will not be very efficient. Any library that may get to work will work only if it is single threaded and then each thread doing all the operations by itself.

Comment: @Pavan: yes, I know, the plan is to do that on a single thread, and the reason is that this operation will have to be done for many such matrices, so instead of putting parallelism on the usual algebra part (especially I am not looking at big matrices), I put parallelism on the computation I am doing with these matrices.

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking for a popular C++ math library that has been shown to work really well, you can try [glm](http://glm.g-truc.net/) for your purposes. It's modeled after GLSL, which means its data is stored in column-major order, which is friendly with all shader/gpu-oriented designs. GLM is a header-only library and purported to be very standards-friendly, so maybe it'll compile properly for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's just an awesome library! It needs more advertising. I have not seen it anywhere before, and looks like it's well supporting CUDA. I'll try that.

Answer (score 0):

What about XNA Math which is distributed with DirectX SDK? It contains special classes for vectors and matrices and tons of special functions for operations on them.

- XMVECTOR
- XMMATRIX
- XMVectorMethodName
- XMMatrixMethodName

Comment: That would have been great, but my project is to be run on Linux, so no DirectX. (I've added the note about that on my post, sorry for not having stated the cross-platform requirement)